# Time scale formatting issues with chartjs, mostly unitStepSize

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am loving chartjs, but I have struggled to get the exact formatting I am after when it comes to my time scale. What I am after is the following:

- Label should never be diagonal (ideally - not a big fan)
- Ideally I'd be able to specify the minimum gap in tick marks, so as to avoid the above, something like 7 days

I have been using the following xAxes setup:

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  unit: 'day',
  unitStepSize: 10,
  minUnit: 'day',
  time: {
    displayFormats: {
      day: 'D-MMM',
      week: 'D-MMM',
      month: 'D-MMM',
      quarter: 'D-MMM',
    }
  }
}]
```

And my dates are consumed in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

Right now it seems to be ignoring the `unitStepSize`.

A full example can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/koendirckx/fqhv8cjs/5/

Answer (score 6):

After struggling with this same issue myself for longer than I should have, I finally noticed the fine print in the Chartjs documentation at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-units  The unitStepSize parameter needs to be defined in the time sub options.

I was doing:

```
 scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day',
                        displayFormats: {
                            day: 'MMM DD',
                        },
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "black",
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
                    },
                    unitStepSize: 7,
                }],
                yAxes: yAxes
            },
```

When I should have been doing:

```
 scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day',
                        displayFormats: {
                            day: 'MMM DD',
                        },
                        unitStepSize: 7,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "black",
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
                    },
                }],
                yAxes: yAxes
            },
```

In a broader context: (note that eleChart1 is the canvas DOM element of the chart, and that yAxis, datasets, and ChartName are objects/variables built outside of the example.)

```
var Chart1 = new Chart(eleChart1, {
        type: 'line',
        lineWidth: 15,
        data: {
            datasets: datasets,
        },
        options: {
            showPointLabels: true,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                //position: "bottom"

            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: ChartName,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontStyle: "bold",
                fontFamily: "Segoe UI"
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day',
                        displayFormats: {
                            day: 'MMM DD',
                        },
                        unitStepSize: 7,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "black",
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
                    },
                }],
                yAxes: yAxes
            },
        }
    });
```

**Bottom line: Once I put the unitStepSize option in the time object, it worked as expected.**